# Natural regression to study rate of convergence from MRW (1992)

Tags: economic-growth, regression

In the paper of Mankiw, Romer and Weil (1992: 422-423) aka MRW there is a transfer from theoretical dynamical model to empirical regression approach as follows.

> The model suggest a natural regression to study the rate of convergence. Equation (13)
> $$ \frac{d \log y(t)}{dt} =  \lambda [\log y^* - \log y(t)]$$
> implies that (14)
> $$\log y(t) = (1 - e^{-\lambda t}) \log y^* + e^{-\lambda t} \log y(0)$$

In the above expression $y^*$ is a constant steady state level of production and $y(0)$ is some initial level. This can also be expressed as:

$$
\log y(t) - \log y(0) = (1 - e^{-\lambda t}) [\log y^* - \log y(0)]
$$

What are intermediate steps between the (13) and (14)? How does $y(0)$ appear in the model?

PS. This is, perhaps, something simple but a tip is needed.
Direct solution for $y$ returns
$$
y = y^* \cdot e^{-e^{-\lambda \cdot t - C_1}}
$$

Comment: Hint:  13 is ODE, start by taking the integral of both sides

Comment: @1muflon1, I've got a solution in general form (below - last line). Though I'm not quite sure how do we convert $C_1$ into $log(y(0))$.

Comment: In ODE you can always find out what C is by solving the problem for initial value that is why you have $y_0$ there

Comment: @1muflon1, thank you, I've figured out finally that they differentiated for $\log y$, not for $y$ (shame on me). Hence, $C_1$ is substituted with $(\log y_0 - \log y^*)$. Is such choice of constant just for convenience?